# How can I check if an instance is in a dataframe in pyspark and get the ocurrence from the dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, row, apache-spark-sql, find-occurrences

I have an instance extracted from a dataframe with 3 different Attributes: Atr1, Atr2 and Atr3.

On the other hand, I have a dataframe containing 4 Attributes: Atr1, Atr2, Atr3, Atr4, but the Atributes Atr1, Atr2 and Atr3 are the same as the previous mentioned instance. I have something like this:

```python
Instance:

[Row(Atr1=u'A', Atr2=u'B', Atr3=24)]

Dataframe:

+------+------+------+------+
| Atr1 | Atr2 | Atr3 | Atr4 |
+------+------+------+------+
|  'C' |  'B' |  21  |  'H' |
+------+------+------+------+
|  'D' |  'B' |  21  |  'J' |
+------+------+------+------+
|  'E' |  'B' |  21  |  'K' |
+------+------+------+------+
|  'A' |  'B' |  24  |  'I' |
+------+------+------+------+
```

So, having the instance above, I want to check whether it exists an instance in the dataframe with those values for attributes Atr1, Atr2 and Atr3 and if it exists, get the value of Atr4. In this case, 'I'.

Answer (score 0):

```
df[(df['Atr1'] == row.Atr1) & (df['Atr2'] == row.Atr2) & (df['Atr3'] == row.Atr3)].Atr4
```

with `row` the Row and `df` the DataFrame you mentionned.

Answer (score 0):

```python
from pyspark.sql.types import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

#sample data
row_list = [Row(Atr1=u'A', Atr2=u'B', Atr3=24),
            Row(Atr1=u'E', Atr2=u'F', Atr3=20),]
df = sc.parallelize([('C', 'B', 21, 'H'),
                     ('D', 'B', 21, 'J'),
                     ('E', 'B', 21, 'K'),
                     ('A', 'B', 24, 'I')]).\
    toDF(["Atr1", "Atr2", "Atr3", "Atr4"])

search_df = df.join(sqlContext.createDataFrame(row_list), ["Atr1", "Atr2", "Atr3"], "right").\
    withColumn("rowItem_Exist", col('Atr4').isNotNull())
search_df.show()
```

Output is:

```
+----+----+----+----+-------------+
|Atr1|Atr2|Atr3|Atr4|rowItem_Exist|
+----+----+----+----+-------------+
|   E|   F|  20|null|        false|
|   A|   B|  24|   I|         true|
+----+----+----+----+-------------+
```